# Populate DropDownList from HttpWebRequest XML VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm new to VB.net and I'm having trouble figuring out how to load the XML data into a DropDownList from a HttpWebRequest. The Data I want to load into the DropDownList is Merchant + Price. Down below is my code:

```
Dim s As HttpWebRequest
s = HttpWebRequest.Create("myURL")
s.Method = "GET"
Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
postresponse = DirectCast(s.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)

Dim postreqreader As New Stream(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

Dim returnData As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

postresponse.Close()
```

The XML response I'm getting back from returnData is:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <ID>123</ID>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <Isbn>123456789</Isbn>
            <Offers>
                  <Offer>
                      <Isbn>123456789</Isbn>
                      <Merchant>Vendor1</Merchant>
                      <Price>3.00</Price>
                      <Shipping>8.00<Shipping>
                  </Offer>
                  <Offer>
                      <Isbn>123456789</Isbn>
                      <Merchant>Verndor2</Merchant>
                      <Price>3.00</Price>
                      <Shipping>8.00<Shipping>
                  </Offer>
             </Offers>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ensure you close your Shipping tags.

Try something like this:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet()
ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(returnData )))

ds.Tables("Offer").Columns.Add("MerchantPrice", GetType(String), "Merchant + ' - ' + Price")

Dim dv As DataView = ds.Tables("Offer").DefaultView
dv.Sort = "Merchant"

ddlMerchant.DataTextField = "MerchantPrice"
ddlMerchant.DataValueField = "Isbn"
ddlMerchant.DataSource = dv
ddlMerchant.DataBind()
```

Comment: Thanks. This work. How would I combine two or multiple fields together in the drop down?

Answer (score 0):

first convert the xml in to dataset using this code

```
    DataSet ds;
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(string);
    ds.ReadXml(reader);
```

and then bind it to DropDownList